# DebugToolbarMiddleware' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, google-developers-console

TypeError at /playground/hello/
'DebugToolbarMiddleware' object is not iterable
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/playground/hello/
Django Version: 4.2
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:
'DebugToolbarMiddleware' object is not iterable
Exception Location: C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\debug_toolbar\panels\templates\panel.py, line 47, in _request_context_bind_template
Raised during:  playground.views.say_hello
Python Executable:  C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.13
Python Path:

['C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\Desktop\storefront\storefront',
'C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\python39.zip',
'C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\DLLs',
'C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib',
'C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3',
'C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\site-packages',
'C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32',
'C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32\lib',
'C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin']
Server time:    Sun, 23 Apr 2023 09:37:08 +0000

I tried but i am not getting

Answer (score 0):

Update Debug Toolbar to the latest version (4.0). Older versions of Debug Toolbar don't support Django 4.2.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).